# Excel - Return Max/Min Value Since

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find a way to return the previous largest/smallest value in a time series since the most recent data point. Please see the attached image

```
Input   Input   Output
Date    Value   Largest Since
10/31/2016  7   …
11/1/2016   10  …
11/2/2016   8   …
11/3/2016   5   …
11/4/2016   6   11/2/2016
11/5/2016   9   11/1/2016
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCPFy.jpg)

So for row 6, I want a formula (no VBA please) that would return the date 11/1/16, as the value 10 in column two with the corresponding date of 11/1/16 was the largest value prior to 11/5/16 (with the associated value 9).

Applying the same formula to 5 should return 11/2/16, given that the value 8 was the last largest value prior to 11/4/16.

I know some combination of rank, index/match, and large/small should get me there, but I can't quite figure it out at the moment.

Thanks!

Comment: Your second paragraph doesn't make sense to me. The highest value prior to 11/4/16 is still 10 isn't it? Why would it be 8?

Comment: Sorry for the vague explanation. I don't want to return largest prior value. I want to return the last time a larger value occurred. So for 11/4/16, the value was 6. The last time a larger value occured was 11/2/16, which had a corresponding value of 8. This is even though the largest prior value was 10 on 11/1/16.

Answer (score 1):

With input dates assumed E1:E8 and Input values F1:F8, I used the following array formula for "Output Largest Since" starting in row H4 : =IFERROR(INDEX(E$1:E$8,MAX(IF($F$1:$F3>F4,ROW(F$1:F3),"")),1),""). I hope this helps.